# How can I detect that a user changes form one to another voice channel?

Tags: discord.js

For example I want to detect when somebody changes from for example "Talk I" to "Talk II".. But it should work without disconnecting the server in the meantime and then join into "Talk II"! Is there a way to do that??

Comment: Be clear what you are asking about. Please follow How to Ask guidelines and ask question related to Programming here with your tried code and output of your code.

Comment: I do think my question is quit specific and easy to understand. But if you don't want to answer anything that matters than it is your business.

Comment: Manorel please read site rules which you can find at the [help], and you'll find out that moderating question and answer quality is all of our concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a user updates their voice status, the client emits a [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event.
To detect if a user has changed their voice channel, you can do something like this:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let oldChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel, // the previous channel, if there was one
    newChannel = newMember.voiceChannel; // the current channel, if there is one

  if (oldChannel != newChannel) { // if the channel has changed
    // do your stuff...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much u helped me a lot... :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)